# Overwrite conflicting mappings silently in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I have a mapping in `.vimrc` that conflicts with another mapping in a plugin.

```
nnoremap <leader>p some fancy command here
```

When I run VIM, I get a warning:

```
E227: mapping already exists for ,p
```

How to overwrite the offending mappings silently?

**Edit**:

- it neither works with `nmap`

Comment: What about `nmap` directly ?

Comment: Set **remap** to true

Comment: `remap` is for recursion, and according to docs it is encouraged to leave it with `no` value. Besides, it does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might squelch the warning:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <leader>p some fancy command here
```

But I suspect the warning isn't actually coming from your mapping. I suspect that the conflicting mapping is defined with `<unique>`, and is being mapped *after* your mapping. `<unique>` will issue an `E227` if a conflicting map already exists. See `:h E227`.

Dig around for a second source of the mapping (plugin, probably) and see if that's the case. Most well-written plugins offer you a way to use your own mappings or overwrite theirs, by setting a global flag to disable mappings entirely, or will detect that you've mapped something else to a specific function (via `hasmapto`)

You can see which plugin/script set a mapping via:

```
:verbose map <leader>p
```

That should help track down the source.

Comment: didn't work with silent, but I *tracked down the source* and disabled he offending plugin

Comment: Just curious, but what was the offending plugin?